# Comparing directories in Emacs

Tags: emacs, diff

I am experimenting with `ediff-directories`, but I am not sure I am using it correctly.

I read in [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html) that, once I supply two directories to `ediff-directories`, if I press `==` Emacs compares them recursively.

However, if I press `==` I only get folders with `=` signs (meaning that the two folders have identical contents) on the level where I run the command. If I want to see which folders have `=` signs at deeper levels in the folder hierarchy, I need to re-run the `==` command at each level.

How can I tell emacs to go recursively all the way to the leaves so that I can see all the differences in the `directory difference buffer` (accessible via the keyboard command `D`)?

If anybody knows of a tutorial on how to use `ediff-directories` (other than the official [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html)), I would be highly interested.

---

Also, if I want to exit a session group (comparison of folders at one level), but I have sessions open for deeper levels, if I press `q` (quit this session group), Emacs complains with the messaage:

> This sesssion group has active sessions---cannot exit

How can I exit session groups without exiting the sub-sessions one by one?

Comment: What I'd pay for ediff to become as usable as [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)...

Comment: `ztree-diff` can diff two directories recursively. https://github.com/fourier/ztree

Answer (score 9):

There is [`ztree`](https://github.com/fourier/ztree) package available from Melpa which supports recursive directory tree comparison: `M-x ztree-diff` using GNU `diff` utilities to compare corresponding files.

If you use [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) then to install and configure `ztree` package, add to your `.emacs`:

```
;; ** recursive directory tree comparison: M-x ztree-diff
(use-package ztree
  :ensure t) ; needs GNU diff utility
```

Answer (score 7):

I have used `M-x dired-compare-directories`, but there is also [EdiffTrees](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffTrees), which might serve you better in the situation you describe.

Comment: There's also a `=` bind if you're already in Dired.

Answer (score 4):

I also needed this feature and came up with the following. The function `ediff-directories-recursive` works like `ediff-directories` but recurses into sub-directories.

The magic behind that is temporarily replacing the built-in `directory-files` by a self-made `directory-files-recursive` before calling `ediff-directories`.

```lisp
(eval
 (let ((directory-files-original (symbol-function 'directory-files)))
   `(defun directory-files-recursive (directory &optional full match nosort)
      "Like `directory-files' but recurses into subdirectories. Does not follow symbolic links."
      (let* ((prefix (or (and full "") directory))
         dirs
         files)
    (mapc (lambda (p)
        (let ((fullname (if full p (concat prefix "/" p))))
          (when (and (file-directory-p fullname)
                 (null (or (string-match "\\(^\\|/\\).$" p)
                       (string-match "\\(^\\|/\\)..$" p)
                       (file-symlink-p fullname))))
            (setq dirs (cons p dirs)))))
          (funcall ,directory-files-original directory full nil nosort))
    (setq dirs (nreverse dirs))
    (mapc (lambda (p)
        (when (null (file-directory-p (if full p (concat prefix "/" p))))
          (setq files (cons p files))))
          (funcall ,directory-files-original directory full match nosort))
    (setq files (nreverse files))
    (mapc (lambda (d)
        (setq files
              (append files
                  (if full
                  (apply 'directory-files-recursive (list d full match nosort))
                (mapcar (lambda (n)
                      (concat d "/" n))
                    (apply 'directory-files-recursive (list (concat prefix "/" d) full match nosort)))))))
          dirs)
    files))))

(eval
 `(defun ediff-directories-recursive (dir1 dir2 regexp)
    "Like `ediff-directories' but recurses into sub-directories. Does not follow symbolic links."
    ,(interactive-form (symbol-function 'ediff-directories))
    (let ((directory-files-original (symbol-function 'directory-files)))
      (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (fset 'directory-files (symbol-function 'directory-files-recursive))
        (ediff-directories dir1 dir2 regexp)
        (fset 'directory-files directory-files-original))))))
```

Comment: I did eval-buffer and got this: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp (autoload "ediff" 890739 t nil))
  interactive-form((autoload "ediff" 890739 t nil))
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add to the `ztree` recommendation above; ztree is awesome. For those sitting on the fence, here is a screenshot..[image]